# Mango Secondary Tiles

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have some doubts regarding secondary tiles.

1. How many secondary tiles can be
   pinned to the start screen for an
   application (is there any limit)
2. Secondary tiles are pinned to the
   start programmatically. Do we have
   to ask the user whether he wants the changes to a particular section to be pinned to the start as secondary tile or without getting any confirmation from the user we can pin the secondary tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no, currently published, restriction on the number of tiles that can be added.

Due to the screen real estate available on the start screen and the value of updated/animating live tiles which aren't always available (or at least in the first few "screens" worth of tiles) becomes decreasingly useful.

While pinning tiles can be done without a user initiated action, when a new tile is added the app closes and the phone returns to the start screnn to show the new tile. As such it's not possible to add lots of live tiles without the user being aware.

If a marketplace requirement isn't added regarding the behaviour around the creation of additional tiles I would expect it to be added quite quickly.

The potentially bad user experience of an app which repeatedly creates additional tiles without a specific instruction from the user would, I strongly expect, lead to that app not getting used much. ;)

In summary:
You can add as many secondary tiles as you wish but only do it when the user requests it and only make the option available to the user when it will add real value.